# Which method is called to get back to the parent activity when back button on action bar is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

Which method is called on the parent activity when back button on the action bar is pressed?
Is is `onCreate` or any other method?

Comment: what do be mean by back button ? hardware back button or action bar <-- button ?

Comment: actionbar back button which brings back to the parent activity

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp which says that `onOptionsItemSelected` is called.